# Javascript Not working when trying to hide and display form in Ruby

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

Iam trying to create a button that displays a form when a user clicks on it. I have tried checking through my code and i have not found any error but the button does not work. Please Help!

```js
//load turbo scripts

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  //assign elements in to variables
  const openProjectButton = document.getElementById('new-project-button')
  const projectPopover = document.getElementById('new-project-popover')


  //check if elements exist

  if (openProjectButton && projectPopover) {
    //attach listener
    openProjectButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //if the popover class contains is-hidden remove it else return nill.
      return projectPopover.classList.contains('is-hidden') ? projectPopover.classList.remove('is-hidden') : null
    }, false)

    //attach listener to cancel button

    const cancelProjectpopover = document.getElementById('cancel-project-popover')
    cancelProjectpopover.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //add back is-hidden
      return projectPopover.classList.add('is-hidden')
    }, false)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1 mr-auto">
  <button id="new-project-button" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto">New</button>
  <div id="new-project-popover" class="project-popover is-hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name this project" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    <button id="cancel-project-popover" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that outer event `'turbolinks:load'` is fired at all? Because when I remove that event listener, everything works as it should:

```js
//assign elements in to variables
const openProjectButton = document.getElementById('new-project-button')
const projectPopover = document.getElementById('new-project-popover')


//check if elements exist

if (openProjectButton && projectPopover) {
  //attach listener
  openProjectButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //if the popover class contains is-hidden remove it else return nill.
    return projectPopover.classList.contains('is-hidden') ? projectPopover.classList.remove('is-hidden') : null
  }, false)

  //attach listener to cancel button

  const cancelProjectpopover = document.getElementById('cancel-project-popover')
  cancelProjectpopover.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //add back is-hidden
    return projectPopover.classList.add('is-hidden')
  }, false)
}
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1 mr-auto">
  <button id="new-project-button" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto">New</button>
  <div id="new-project-popover" class="project-popover is-hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name this project" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    <button id="cancel-project-popover" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How exactly do i do that. I have installed the gem and required it in my application.js file

Comment: Can you try using the event `page:load`? I'm guessing here, as I have no experience with turbolinks and am just parsing the docs